# How to get the ID of a API from AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have created an API in Amazon API Gateway using the web browser. Now How can I get the ID of the API that I have just created???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you'd rather not kick out to a terminal window you can grab the RestApi ID from the URL in the browser:

```
https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region={region}#/apis/{api-id}/...
```

Answer (score 44):

It can be found using the following command

```
aws apigateway get-rest-apis
```

needless to say you need to setup aws cli

Comment: If you have jq installed, then this might also help when scripting things:
    `REST_ID=$(aws apigateway get-rest-apis | jq -r '.items[] | .id') ; 
    aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id $REST_ID --stage-name dev`

Answer (score 4):

To add another answer, on the AWS console, access the "API Gateway", and look for your API, it is shown right there in the list.

[image]